# How to set friendly name for a Google Service Account?

Tags: google-api

Is it possible to set a friendly name on a service account? When listing the Google Accounts a file is shared with on Drive, it shows each user's friendly name and their avatar. I'd like to set this information on the service account so it's more apparent *what it is*. Currently it looks like a memory corruption when the list reads John, Bob, Mike, 470187621257-kj55n6oekpq7f91ggcap2sgk34s1aq2v@developer.gserviceaccount.com.

Bonus: how to set the avatar picture.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're stuck with checking the [permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions) and comparing the `type` to use `type + " Account"` so that it at least looks cleaner (e.g. "Domain Account").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google recently introduced the ability to set names for service accounts! You can set it on [this page](https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/permissions/serviceaccounts).